# Is Alloy an example of Answer Set Programming

Tags: alloy, answer-set-programming

I've been looking at ASP and am wondering about the relationship between these two approaches since they both use SATsolvers at the backend.although there is little or no overlap in the literature.  I'd appreciate a simple comparision of the two.

(This question was also asked on the CS StackExchange

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14633/why-is-alloy-not-an-answer-set-programming-system

)